# Given a material point that goes on a circular trajectory, of radius R, in the z=0 plane, write the intrinsic components for the velocity

Tags: mechanical-engineering

So, I know it's a long shot but my Mechanics exam is coming up in less than a week and my course is really vague and poorly structured. Also, it has all these exercises with no example at all, so I'm kinda stuck.

Would anyone guide me through this problem please? The following ones are similar in structure, and I'm sure that if I understand this one, I'll be able to do the other ones alone.

Answer (score 0):

The trajectory you described can be represented as x^2+y^2=R^2.
So the velocity in x direction will be 2x and that in y direction will be 2y. 
The resultant velocity at any point will be√[4x^2+4y^2]=2R.

Comment: How did you figure out that x and y are equal to 4? Random example?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. First, I mistakenly took r=8. Now it has been corrected.